# Problem Updating the the contents of Dictionary in foreach loop

Tags: c#, dictionary, extension-methods

I am writing a simple generic update extension for IEnumerable, this method used to join given 2 List of business objects or dictionaries using the given keys and updating the specific field.

```
public static void Update<TOuter, TInner, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, IEnumerable<TInner> Inner, Func<TOuter, TKey> OuterKeySelector, Func<TInner, TKey> InnerKeySelector,Action<TOuter,TInner> updator)
        {
            ILookup<TKey, TInner> innerLookup = Inner.ToLookup(InnerKeySelector, element => element);

            foreach (TOuter outerItem in outer)
            {
                TKey key = OuterKeySelector(outerItem);
                if (innerLookup.Contains(key))
                {
                    foreach (TInner innerItem in innerLookup[key])
                    {
                        updator(outerItem, innerItem);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

This works fine in normal objects, for ex:

```
      List<testObject> obj1 = new List<testObject>()
       {
           new testObject(){fruitId=1,name="mango"},
           new testObject(){fruitId=2,name="grapes"},
           new testObject(){fruitId=2,name="grapes"},
           new testObject(){fruitId=4,name="kivi"},
       };

       List<testObject> obj2 = new List<testObject>()
       {
           new testObject(){fruitId=2,name="apple"},
           new testObject(){fruitId=4,name="orange"},
       };

        obj1.Update(obj2,
             tx => tx.fruitId,
             ty => ty.fruitId,
            (tx,ty)=>tx.name=ty.name);
```

But, i cannot use this method with dictionary,

```
       Dictionary<string, int> first = new Dictionary<string, int>()
       {
           {"a",1},
           {"b",2},
           {"c",9},
           {"e",5},               
       };
       Dictionary<string, int> second = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
           {"a",8},
           {"b",2},
           {"e",20}               
       };
       var kk = 0;

       first.Update(second,
           f1 => f1.Key,
           s1 => s1.Key,
           (f1, s1) => f1.Value = s1.Value);
```

it gives the below error

> Property or indexer
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair.Value'
>   cannot be assigned to -- it is read
>   only

I know there is a restriction, by MSDN

> Enumerators can be used to read the
>   data in the collection, but they
>   cannot be used to modify the
>   underlying collection.

is there a hack/workaround to achive the same functionality in a generic manner?

Comment: Have you tried second[f1.Key] = s1.Value?

Comment: @andyp, its first[f1.Key] = s1.Value.. i tried that too.. But it gives an error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Comment: If you really want to do that, you could write
`foreach (TOuter outerItem in outer.ToList())` in your extension...

Comment: @digEmAll, not working. whatever change yo do, it still return the list of key value  pairs..:)

Comment: @Ramesh: I meant andyp solution (i.e. `second[f1.Key] = s1.Value`) plus mine (i.e. `foreach` modification in the extension). I've tested it and it works (even if is not so elegant)

Comment: @digEmAll, another way to solve this problem is switch your inner & outer classes. Class that needs to be updated should be inner, so this avoids the modiable collection to enter into the enumuration.. check out my answer below...

Comment: @Ramesh: eh eh good trick :) Anyway, I'm still thinking you should allow modifications only on inner Property of object. It sounds safer to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to solve this problem is to switch your inner & outer classes. Class that needs to be updated should be inner, so this avoids the modiable collection to enter into the enumuration..

```
       second.Update(first1,
           s1 => s1.Key,
           f1 => f1.Key,   
          (f1, s1) => first1[s1.Key] = f1.Value);
```

Thanks **andyp & digEmAll**

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems reasonable if you look it in the same manner for `List` as for `Dictionary`.

In your list example you have a `List<MyMutableType>` and you update a `Property` of the MyMutableType object in a certain position in the list.

In your dictionary example you have a `Dictionary<Key,MyNotMutableType>` and you are trying to substitute a `MyNotMutableType` instance in a certain position with another `MyNotMutableType` instance, you're not trying to simply change a `Property` of the same object instance.

Following the approach used for List you should have a dictionary like:
`Dictionary<Key,MyMutableType>` and in your updater delegate you should only update a Property of the  `MyMutableType`.

Hope this help (and sorry for my poor english)

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is not because of the inability to modify the dictionary while you are enumerating a collection, this is a runtime error. It is, as the error says, that the KeyValuePair does not have a setter on the Value parameter. so f1.Value == s1.Value is not allowed. Essentially KeyValuePair is immutable as you can't change the values.

If you want this type of functionality I would recommend that you create a more specific Update that takes a Dictionary specifically rather than a IEnumerable.

In terms of working around the fact that dictionaries are readonly when the are being enumerated I don't know an answer.